# Access static data from a tableless model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have to load static data in combo boxes. Is posible store the data in model it self, access this data form a tableless model.

My data is like this

```
[{:id=>1, :name=>"xyz1", :value=>"001"}, {:id=>2, :name=>"xyz2", :value=>"002"}, {:id=>3, :name=>"xyz3", :value=>"003"}]
```

Comment: put the data in a YAML file and load it into your app.

Comment: If the data the model specific, you can use a constant with the values

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create model in 'app/models/some_data.rb'

```
class SomeData
  attr_accessors :id, :name, :value
end
```

Then you can use it as normal Ruby object. Then you can use some ActiveModel modules, to gain some special behavior: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.7/activerecord/README.rdoc